# Get a return value from arbitrary eval'd code

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a requirement that the user can provide arbitrary statements which can be stored in a function and called later to get a return value. A simple example of this is that `userInput` might be

```
var x = 10;
x;
```

I would store this via

```
var callback = function() {
    return eval(userInput);
}
```

and then running `callback()` returns `10` as expected.

However, I also need to support the case with an explicit return statement, ie `userInput` might be

```
var x = 10;
return x;
```

In this case the eval method above will fail with `SyntaxError: return not in function`. Instead I could store callback as

```
var callback = new Function(userInput);
```

My issue is that I would like to combine these two approaches according the rule 'get explicit return value otherwise get the result of the last executed statement'. In particular this can't be done with analysis of the code at callback creation time as the user could potentially do something odd like

```
if(envVar < 10)
    return a;
b * 0.5;
```

which combines both.

Any thoughts on how to structure the creation of the `callback` function to accommodate these possible inputs? Unfortunately it is not possible to enforce one style or the other on the user.

---

**UPDATE** to answer some of the comments below.

One solution suggested is to search for a return token and choose between `new Function` and `eval`. This doesn't work for my last example, see http://jsfiddle.net/ZGb6z/2/ - out4 should be `"no"` but ends up being undefined as the last executed statement is not returned.

Another suggestion is to modify the user input to add an explicit return on the last line if one is not found. Unfortunately it's not possible to know which statement will be executed last. Consider

```
var x = 10;
switch(x) {
  case 10:
    100;
    break;
  default:
    200;
    break;
}
```

When called it should return `100`, but it would take some serious analysis to determine where to put returns for arbitrary code.

Comment: Seems like a horrible idea to eval user data, but anyway -> http://jsfiddle.net/ZGb6z/

Comment: why not just use Function() and revert to eval() if undefined?

Comment: @dandavis Per my comment to Nico's answer, if the user-code has side effects on the environment I don't want it to be run twice

Comment: The return statement specifies  the value to be returned by a function. The following code is invalid: var x = 10; return x; My question is: why do you want to support it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGb6z/3/ : out4 is "no" if you return it...

Comment: @GuyCook what exactly is the use case here? This seems like a horrible idea unless you are building something for a very small set of trusted users and if that is the case then wouldn't it be easier to just tell them what the required input style is?

Comment: Another note: with the `switch` `case` `break` example wouldn't `break;` be the last statement executed? There is a reason that functions don't return the last statement result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either manage your expectations or manage your user's expectations. `eval` and `new Function()` are not suitable for your requirements if you require mixed usage of explicit and non-explicit `return` statements in the same user-input. You will continue to find issues following either of these routes.

Simply searching for the word `return` is not sufficient either... `var returning = true;` or `var a = 'return';` or `/* return true */ true;` will all throw false positives.

**Managing your expectations:** To do such a thing you require a form of [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and parser, at which point you can do away with `eval` entirely and execute your own safe functions based on the parsed input. This is the best approach when execution of user input has to occur anyway as you can ensure that nothing gets executed you do not wish to permit. If you want to cover these sort of edge cases and permit strange user input then you must be prepared to increase the size and development time of your application. I have built a few applications executing user generated code and have always come to the conclusion this is the correct route to go down.

**Managing your user's expectations:** Provide a guide, tell them not to mix explicit returns with non-explicit returns, these are strange coding practices anyway. Better yet explicitly tell them to include or omit the return statement. There is no shame in asking your users to follow them, especially if it allows you to improve their experience elsewhere.

Comment: I've given you the bounty as whilst this isn't the answer I'd _hoped_ for, it looks like the road I'm going to have to go down. For the time being I'll be advising users to explicitly provide the return keyword though it will break a whole lot of existing code for those that don't update/carefully read the docs :(

Comment: @GuyCook It's not the sort of answer I'd hoped to give either :(

Answer (score 5):

Just use a `try` `catch`, manipulating the input will be very painful for you, and `try` `catch` can't really make your code any more obtuse at this point.

```
var failback = function () {
  try {
    return eval(userInput);
  } catch (e) {
    return Function(userInput);
  }
};
```

What I would really suggest is investing in a parser, kind of like [how Angular does it](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js). That kind of thing would prevent your users from doing whatever the hell they want, introducing attack vectors, yadda, yadda, yadda.

Comment: I very seriously considered going down the try/catch road, my primary concern is that the user code could have side effects and should only be executed once, and I don't believe the syntax error is thrown until it's reached, thereby causing the side effects again when retried as a function

Answer (score 0):

There I was thinking I'd only see problems like this at the code golf stack exchange :)

My solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/hKq87/1

It essentially replaces the 'return' statement with an exception that has a special string prefixed to it. If we see that string, we know we are actually returning a value, and return it rather than re-raising the exception.

The reason I chose to throw an exception rather than replace the `return` statement with a function call was because it is hard to know where the JS code evaluated for the `return` really ends. It could be split across multiple lines, contain several special characters and may not even have the optional semi-colon at the end. So I concatenate a string to whatever the value being returned is and `throw` it, as the `throw` keyword doesn't require it's argument to be wrapped in parentheses.

In addition, throwing exceptions provides me a convenient way to immediately terminate execution of the code block, without halting other JS execution.

Here is the callback method:

```
var callback = function(userInput) {
    var returned = undefined;
    userInput = userInput.replace(/(^|[\(\\)[\]{};,\s])return(\s*[^\s;])?/gi, function(m, b, e){ 
        return b + " throw '__RETURNED_VALUE'" +
            (e !== undefined ? "+" + e : "");
    });
    try {
        returned = eval(userInput);
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.indexOf("__RETURNED_VALUE") == 0) {
            returned = e.substring("__RETURNED_VALUE".length) || undefined; 
        }
        else {
            throw e; 
        }
    }
    return returned;
}
```

The regex above accounts for variables that may end with the string "return", that we would not want to replace as it is not a `return` statement. It also allows for return statements within braces, without trailing semi-colons or at the very beginning/end.

One issue with the current method is that you can not use the (rare) comma operator in a `return` statement, or expect numerical values to be returned correctly. The last test case in the jsfiddle demonstrates this. An example from [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/):

```
//original
return 5 * 2 + 3,  22;
//modified
 throw '__RETURNED_VALUE='+ 5 * 2 + 3,  22;
//apply * operator
 throw '__RETURNED_VALUE='+ 10 + 3,  22;
//apply + operators
 throw '__RETURNED_VALUE=103',  22;
//apply , operator
 throw 22;
```

This problem can be avoided by completely eliminating the prefix '__RETURNED_VALUE=' and just replacing 'return' with 'throw'. However, this means that the code provided must run without throwing exceptions, which I thought to be a harder constraint than just crafting return statements to be simple (avoiding comma operators, non-parenthesized arithmetic, etc.). In addition, if a user ever creates a return statement that we can't handle with the current code, we conveniently throw an exception for it so it easily comes to our attention.

Comment: An interesting approach, but I think it has a few issues that will crop up given the nature of the user code that could be supplied. In particular I don't think any regex can be used that will avoid replacing returns in functions defined in user code (ie, will need a lex/parse for that anyway). Also that implementation precludes returning objects (could be solved be wrapping in an object maybe?). The biggest issue is getting caught in the user's own error handling

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/scC4q/)***

Lets assume your user can be a little smarter than the average bear. We are going to ask them to specifically provide an initial value and then a callback with an expression for that value.

The main benefit of doing this is that you avoid eval, and actually have a nice implementation that is re-usable as opposed to being subject to later refactoring.

This way also provides a separation of where the input comes from and where the examination comes from. Although the provided example only shows integer input, really it could be another call with absolutely no knowledge of the value aside that it needs to conform to the callback logic.

```
function expression(x,callback){
 return callback(x);
}

out1.innerHTML = expression(8,function(x){
 return x;
});
out2.innerHTML = expression(10,function(x){
 return x;
});
out3.innerHTML = expression(10,function(x){
 if(x === 10) return "yes"; "no";
});
out4.innerHTML = expression(8,function(x){
 return x === 10 ? "yes" : "no";
});
```